# Placing Jquery validation error inside <input> box?

Tags: jquery, validation, input, errorplacement

My problem:

After validating an input field, if validation isn't complete, i want to put the error-message into the orginal input field.

you can user insertAfter() and insertBefore() to, (duh!) insert after or before input field.

I couldn't find any solution to my problem on StackOverFlow.

Comment: You should at first ask a question and then answer it in the answer section not in the question's body, what problem does this solve?

Comment: so that's removing value filled by user?! As user, i wouldn't expect/want that

Comment: Undefined: My reputation isn't high enough to answer my own question, a couple of hours, and i can.

Comment: A.wolff: the script doesn't remove any values filled by user. It puts error message in input field, if input was required and not filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO HERE IS MY SOLUTION:

THIS SCRIPT PLACES ERROR IN YOUR INPUT ELEMENT!

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#theForm").validate({

            errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
                element.val(error[0].outerText);
            },
            debug: true
        });
    });
```

Additionally you will need a script to remove the message when input is clicked.

G'day!